# why is ansible not being installed on an EC2 instance that is provisioned through terraform?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ansible, terraform

I am attempting to install ansible on an EC2 instance after provisioning the instance using terraform. The script I am using has the installation for AWS CLI and jenkins, and these scripts seem to be workin fine. But the ansible scripts doesn't seem to be working. If I run the script manually in the terminal, it seems to work fine.

This is the code for the installation.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y

# Installing Ansible
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
echo 'PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
pip3 install --user ansible 

sleep 20

#install jenkins
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk -y 

wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install jenkins -y

sleep 20

#AWS CLI Install
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
sudo apt install unzip -y
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

This is the code for the terraform resource, and the installations.sh file above is called in the user data section of the ec2_instance resource.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web_server" {
    ami = var.ami
    instance_type = var.instance_type
    key_name = var.key_name
    vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids
    subnet_id = var.public_subnet_id
    associate_public_ip_address = var.associate_public_ip_address
    user_data = data.template_file.installations.rendered
    
    tags = {
        Name = "Web_server"
}

}

data "template_file" "installations" {
  template = file("../Terraform/scripts/installations.sh")
}
```

Comment: Hi junaid, welcome to SO. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, as you have not included any definition of "doesn't seem to be working" nor how you determined if something is or isn't working, nor any troubleshooting steps you've taken so far. This question also appears to have nothing to do with programming, which makes it a better fit for https://ServerFault.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I run your UserData script on Ubuntu 18.04 using terraform in an attempt to replicate your issue, but the script executes **without any problems**. Thus whatever issues you are experiencing their origin is outside of the UserData.

Nevertheless, if you want to **debug your script**, you have to ssh into the instance and inspect `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`. If your userdata produces any errors, they should be listed in that file.